# Synchronous Meteor.method hangs on call

Tags: meteor, methods

I'm building a Meteor app that exchanges data with a 3rd party API and I need a method that will run synchronously to exchange a refresh token for an access token if the token is expired.

I'm using the below in one method:

```
tokenExpiration = Meteor.user().services.box.expiresAt
if Date.now() - tokenExpiration > 0
  Meteor.call("refreshToken")
else
  console.log("Token valid. Proceed with call to Box API")
```

The `refreshToken` method starts like this, just like any other method would:

```
Meteor.methods(
  refreshToken: ->
    ...LOGIC HERE...
)
```

I know the logic is ok because if I put that directly in the original method (above) it works fine. The problem is that when I use `Meteor.call("refreshToken")` in the original method Meteor just hangs that line and refuses to move any further. The original method is called from the client but the rest is all happening on the server.

I don't see anything wrong, am I missing something?

Comment: any errors on server or client console?

Comment: Nope, nothing. The same `Meteor.call("refreshToken")` works fine in another method that I'm calling synchronously. Are there issues with calling a synchronous method inside a method that is being run asynchronously?

Comment: try adding some logging right before the method call, and also right at the top of the method being called synchronously itself to make sure its actually getting there.

Comment: Logs show the script gets there immediately before the method call but never actually enters the called method. I can't figure it out!

Comment: do you have a `return` in your method function? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095352/meteor-method-hangs-on-call